np.save() works with reproducible example but not mith my own numpy array ("NotImplementedError")
np.save() works with a reproducible example but not with my data.
How can I save my numpy array as binary?
np.save works in this reproducible example:
a = np.arange(12, dtype='float32').reshape(2,2,3)
a.shape
Out[42]: (2, 2, 3)
a.dtype
Out[43]: dtype('float32')
np.save("delme",a)

But not with my numpy array variable_data:
variable_data.shape
Out[45]: (3500, 480, 640)
variable_data.dtype
Out[46]: dtype('float32')
ma.is_masked(variable_data)
Out[52]: False

Then, I get an error:
np.save("delme2", variable_data)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[41], line 3
      1 variable_data.shape
      2 variable_data.dtype
----> 3 np.save("delme2", variable_data)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/sediment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py:546, in save(file, arr, allow_pickle, fix_imports)
    544 with file_ctx as fid:
    545     arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
--> 546     format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
    547                        pickle_kwargs=dict(fix_imports=fix_imports))

File ~/miniforge3/envs/sediment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py:730, in write_array(fp, array, version, allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs)
    728 else:
    729     if isfileobj(fp):
--> 730         array.tofile(fp)
    731     else:
    732         for chunk in numpy.nditer(
    733                 array, flags=['external_loop', 'buffered', 'zerosize_ok'],
    734                 buffersize=buffersize, order='C'):

File ~/miniforge3/envs/sediment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py:6221, in MaskedArray.tofile(self, fid, sep, format)
   6208 def tofile(self, fid, sep="", format="%s"):
   6209     """
   6210     Save a masked array to a file in binary format.
   6211 
   (...)
   6219 
   6220     """
-> 6221     raise NotImplementedError("MaskedArray.tofile() not implemented yet.")

NotImplementedError: MaskedArray.tofile() not implemented yet.


Try np.save("delme2", variable_data.data)

A ma masked array actually consists of two arrays, data and mask.  save can write one array, but no one has set up a version the will handle both. You could roll your own using np.savez.

Short answer: Your Numpy array variable_data actually seems to be of type MaskedArray, which cannot be saved using np.save(). To save its data as a regular Numpy array, use np.save("delme2", variable_data.data), as suggested in @maciek97x's comment.
Long answer
The fact that ma.is_masked(variable_data) returns False just tells us that there are no masked values in variable_data; it does not tell us anything specific about the type of variable_data.
What does tell us about the type of variable_data is the error trace that you get: The message "MaskedArray.tofile() not implemented yet." tells us that variable_data apparently is a Numpy array of type MaskedArray, which, according to the error message, cannot be saved using np.save().
(You could verify the type of variable_data by printing type(variable_data), by the way.)
However, as you actually don't make use of masking in your array (ma.is_masked(variable_data) returns False, as we have seen), you can just extract the data from your masked array as a regular Numpy array, using variable_data.data. You can then save this regular Numpy array using np.save().
Altogether, you will end up with: np.save("delme2", variable_data.data).

Many thanks to all of you. I wish this explanation were included in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Actually this is more of a MaskedArray documentation issue, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.tofile.html. I don't see any section about available saving methods.  There are a few other to... methods,   If you use MaskedArrays you should be familiar with the two components and how to access them.  MaskedArrays is an old numpy subclass,  and not heavily used. I suspect pandas is used instead.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#conversion MaskedArray  conversion methods.  Looks like pickle is available, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#pickling-and-copy

I just discovered that a.dump(file) can pickle a masked array.  And np.load(file, allow_pickle=True) can load it.

@hpaulj Good catch! I wonder why this is not the approach that is used by MaskedArray.tofile, rather than raising NotImplementedError.

As pointed out by others, with False mask, you don't need to save the whole MaskedArray, just the data.  But in a more general case, you can use the pickle mechanism.
In [279]: import pickle

Make a masked array:
In [280]: arr  = np.ma.MaskedArray(data=np.arange(10), mask=np.arange(10)%2==0); arr
Out[280]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 1, --, 3, --, 5, --, 7, --, 9],
             mask=[ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,
                    True, False],
       fill_value=999999)

Use the documented dump method:
In [281]: arr.dump('matest')    
In [282]: %ls matest
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is DAAD-D296

 Directory of C:\Users\14256

05/23/2024  09:23 AM               382 matest
               1 File(s)            382 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  59,501,572,096 bytes free

Reload using the pickle.load:
In [283]: with open('matest','rb') as f: data=pickle.load(f)

In [284]: data
Out[284]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 1, --, 3, --, 5, --, 7, --, 9],
             mask=[ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,
                    True, False],
       fill_value=999999)

Regular numpy arrays can also be pickled.  If an array contains non-array elements (object dtype) it will actually pickle those.  Conversely, pickle of regular array actually uses the save code to serialize it.  So they work interactively.
With that in mind, I just tried np.load:
In [286]: np.load('matest', allow_pickle=True)
Out[286]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 1, --, 3, --, 5, --, 7, --, 9],
             mask=[ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,
                    True, False],
       fill_value=999999)

